# Why can't I do anything with my columns in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

So far I have imported a data set with columns labeled with things people are afraid of "snakes, heights, spiders, etc.) and each row is a number (1,2,3) representing a different person. So each person rated how much each thing scared them using 1-5.

I  cleared the data so the NAs are gone. Now every time I go to do calculations in the data set, it tells me

> Error: object 'fear.of.public.speaking' not found

Comment: could you share some code please

Comment: You might find [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269) useful here.